# Is it possible to fit a model to a vector outcome?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a data set with 60 features. 10 of these features are target variables in 1/0 format.

Using caret and e.g. random forest I could fit 10 separate models on each of the 10 target features.

My question is, is it possible to fit a model to a vector?

Suppose for the e.g. 1st observation the ten target variables are `c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)`. I could create a model for each where the outcome is either 0 or 1.

My question is, is there some way to fit a model on a vector of outcomes so that I only need to fit one model not 10?

Comment: As I understand your sole aim is to make model fitting more concise, and to actually still fit 10 separate models, right? In that case, I guess the answer is negative as `y` is supposed, when using `train`, to be "*A numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample.*". If you wanted to do a kind of multivariate model, you could transform your vector into a factor. But in that case there would be some serious problems when the vector is long enough.

Comment: Really a methodological question, but yes, you can have a matrix on hte LHS or regression functions.

Comment: This is called multi-label classification. It can be done in mlr, take a look at [this](https://pat-s.github.io/mlr/articles/tutorial/devel/multilabel.html). I am not sure, but think it can not be done in caret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, caret does not support multiple outputs. See e.g. here (https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/466#issuecomment-317527852) where the author of caret confirms this.